# mixpanel gem breaks cucumber tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, mixpanel

i'm using cucumber+capybara to test my app. But after adding mixpanel to my code i've got errors

```
Mixpanel::ConnectionError at /users =================================== > Could not write to Mixpanel, server responded with 200 returning: '{"status": 0, "error": "distinct_id, missing or empty"}'
```

how can i fix it?